# Using Login Form for OAuth Authorization in Spring

Tags: java, spring, oauth, spring-security

I'm using Spring Oauth2 and the Authentication (`/oauth/authorize`) works with http-basic authentication.

Now i want to change this to a `<form-login>`. (I already have a login form, which I want to use)
But every time i insert the `<security:form-login />` tag, I get the following error:

> ...org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   unique bean of type
>   [org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter]
>   is defined: expected single matching bean but found 2:
>   [org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter#0,
>   org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter#1]....

How is it possible to use the same Filter?